# Working around phantomjs crashes in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, protractor, ghostdriver

Is there any way to work around the fact that phantomjs and protractor don't work well together?  (basically this issue here: https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/328)

What I want to do is to check before my test if the phantomjs browser has crashed (i.e. browser is not open.)  If it has, I want to start a new instance of phantomjs and continue the rest of my tests (bonus if I can re-run the test that failed due to crash).

One approach that I haven't had success with looks like this:

```
    var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    var newDriver = new webdriver.Builder().
        withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
        build();
    var wrapper = protractor.wrapDriver(newDriver);

    protractor.setInstance(wrapper);
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    driver = ptor.driver;
    driver.get(URL);
```

Note that I need to open a non-angular page to start, hence the driver.get.  In this case I can get another browser to open, but protractor doesn't hook onto it like I want to.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to start fresh phantomjs instance after each test. Also they say that phantomjs 2.0 is much more stable then 1.9 version.

> https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/557
>
> https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/328